# Check the count of records from the source file and the loaded target

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have some source file suppose mydata.csv and my target table.I want to validate the record count whether it's same between the source file and the target table .The target table is in hive.

I have gone through this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900886/get-row-count-from-all-tables-in-hive)

I want something like

```
if [ eval target_count_command -eq count_from_csv ]
then 
echo "File loaded fine"
else
"LOad Again"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to *count records* would be `wc -l`. If you have a *variable* with the number of CSV lines that should be referenced as `"$count_from_csv"` (with the [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)). You shouldn't need to use `eval` in this case; instead you'll want to *run the command* to count the target number of rows using `"$(target_count_command)`.

Comment: I have my target_count_command as :                                                   ./hive -e 'select count(*) from  Taget_table'  .This will return me the count but i don't think "$( ./hive -e 'select count(*) from  Taget_table'  ) will work here.Either we need to store this commands result in some variable and then compare it to the source file count.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why you think it won't work? I've used this construct hundreds of times.